# Simulating "Increase Font Size" in PowerPoint VBA

Tags: vba, com, powerpoint, textrange

In PowerPoint, if I've selected text with multiple sizes, I can hit the "Increase Font Size" or "Decrease Font Size" to have each `TextRange` grow/shrink by one "step" :

[image: Increase/Decrease Font Size icons]

I almost have a manual solution as follows:

```
Sub GrowText(ByRef t_range as TextRange)
    Dim sub_range as TextRange
    For Each sub_range in SplitBySizes(t_range)
        sub_range.Font.size = NextSize(sub_range.Font.size)
    Next sub_range
End Sub
```

The `NextSize` function uses a static array `(8, 9, 10, 10.5, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 32, 26, 40, 44, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 80, 88, 96)` to find the next biggest font size, and I know how to implement it. What I don't know how to do is implement `SplitBySizes`, which should return an `Array` of `TextRange` objects with text having the same size. Is there a way of doing that without looping character by character? I'm eventually going to move this code into a COM application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something based on this instead:

```
For each sub_range in t_range.Runs
```

Each bit of text with formatting different from the previous text is a Run.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FontSizeIncrease")
```

You will want to add some error checks